# Possible to Power an IP camera from Pi

Tags: camera, power-supply

I have a raspberry pi 3 b+.
I was thinking instead of using an USB camera or the camera module would it be possible to connect an IP camera?
The raspberry pi will be powered by a battery and the pi itself will be disconnected from the network.
I am doing this for an outside project and I want to fit a better camera to the pi.
I am sure a cross-over cable will connect/resolve the dhcp address for the camera but I am unsure how to power it all.
Every time I Google for such stuff I am directed to usb/camera modules and/or poe solutions but running off a hub.
I will of course keep lookign but thought I maximise my progress by psoting here.

thanks

Comment: You don't need a crossover cable.  The Pi (and probably the camera, although it doesn't matter) has [auto MDI-X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-dependent_interface#Auto_MDI-X).

Comment: Hi, yes just recently found that out! Which is cool.
I just need to know how to power it and I am good thanks:)

Comment: How much power does the camera need? You can get 5v or 3.3v from gpio.

Comment: Also, https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin2_5v_power has Rpi gpio pin explanations.

Comment: Most IP cameras are powered off of PoE, so you'd need a PoE injector to provide power to the IP camera. These run at relatively high voltages compared to the Pi, so it's probably not possible. You'd probably be better off going with a USB camera - just plug and play.